# How to set unset session variable back?

Tags: php, session, variables, unset

I'm trying to test my php script, so I need to (at least temporarily) get back some of the unset variables.

I mean:

page1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['var']="somevalue";
go_to("./page2.php");
?>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
use($_SESSION['var']);
unset($_SESSION['var']);
?>
```

Now when I go to page1->page2, then page1 again (then page2 again) page2 does not recognize `$_SESSION['var']`, so I need something like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['var']))
{
set_back($_SESSION['var']); //But how ?
}
```

in page1.php.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Save the original value in `$_SESSION['temp_var']`?

Comment: You've shredded your document and now asking for un-shredder? :-)

Comment: @Boaz thanks, that's a good idea. I thought of another workaround like $_SESSION['var']['active']=1 or 0 since my 'var' was already an array. But I still want to know if there is a way to undo unset.
zerkms no, fortunately I haven't lost anything yet :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is the local browser cache.

When you go back to `page1` the response is served from your computer cache instead from the server so the session variable is not set again

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in php that "rolls back" a session/variable that has been unset (Of course you could store the original value in temporarily session like Boaz suggested). What exactly are you trying to achieve?